# Playing both the pc sound and mic playback through headphones

Tags: flute, microphones, headphones, effects, reverb

I have [downloaded](http://www.gutgroove.com/effectogram-sound-effects-processor.html) this marvelous program called "Effectogram" in order to easily and rapidly (performance-wise) control:

- microphone input volume
- microphone output volume
- playback reverberation
- playback dry sound

  ---

I have a wide list of drivers to choose from, but all of them seem'd to playback with a delay. All of them except for the "ASIO" driver.
I could literally play with a flute, but instead of hearing the original physical flute's sound, hearing amplified and enhanced sounds from my DJ headphones ("Numark Red Wave"). And this is only possible by virtue of the ASIO driver.

---

The problem is that I cannot hear other sounds from the PC, while using ASIO as it seems that it roots it through my laptop speakers instead.
If I could just somehow manage to play beats and bgm(s) my life would suddenly become happier.

---

Using "JACK" didn't help regarding the delay. So.. the enigma is how can I achieve this, playing sounds form my PC and the ASIO Mic-in / Mic-out both through my headphones?

Comment: This seems pretty specific to the program and may be out-of-scope for this stack. The problem is with Effectogram right? 

Someone may be able to point you in the right direction if you give a bit more info about your machine though - are you Win10? OSX? Vivid Vervet?

Comment: The program is clearly not in Effectogram O_O That happens if I attend to use ASIO from FL Studio as well. It is the driver that doesn't roots the pc stream.

Comment: The problem is called "latency". Supposedly ASIO drivers have lower latency than other drivers but they still create a problem.

Comment: However, it is not necessarily to be due to high latency as some drivers just have bigger buffer in order to process the sound qualitatively.

Answer (score 1):

You need an audio interface (hardware device with mic/line inputs/output and a USB or FireWire computer connection) that allows both "direct monitoring" ([Focusrite's description](http://us.focusrite.com/answerbase/what-is-direct-monitoring)), and has a software mixer that lets you listen to both the input AND other audio from your computer.

I think most interfaces these days have direct monitoring, but I'm not sure how common the mixing feature is.  I used to use a TASCAM US-144, and I don't think it allowed you to monitor external input, AND an arbitrary audio source from your computer at the same time.  Currently, I use a Focusrite Pro-40 which definitely does allow what you want.

Comment: I've advanced in this area of expertise. Can say that Virtual Audio Cable, The newest version of ASIO (with some unneeded modules turned off) and a recording software such as Voxengo and a mixer is an interface capable of mixing ASIO stream with directX rec. playback driver (stereo mix for other computers).